# Color removal followed by transparency reproduction

Tags: color, transparency, color-reproduction

I have a large number of images I'd like to remove the background color of and replace with 100% transparent background. I also have semi-transparent rectangles which I need to "color correct".

To illustrate my case here is an example PNG image: Magenta background. 40% transparency yellow rectangle on top of a fully opaque blue circle.

[image]

Removing the background, which is straight forward, I get this:

[image]

So now my question is how do I get the rectangle to be a transparent yellow instead of the orange tint it originally had, while at the same time keep the color of the overlapping area between circle and rectangle?

[image]

I'm looking for any kind of solution. It could be program specific or code based (algorithm).

Comment: Indexed colour doesn't support semi-transparency.

Comment: @BillyKerr my bad. I am also converting these images to rgba

Comment: What information there is (either in the image file or inputted to the automate, not only between your ears) of the original color content? What data (=cold undeniable facts, no guesses) the wanted automate would use to decide there was no orange, but 40% transparent yellow on magenta? One such fact could be "the artist did his whole life work by drawing only circles and rectangles, there's no other forms".

Comment: @user287001 well the bg color is magenta (#FF00FF) and nothing else. Magenta is specifically used for the bg and never used on any shape or object. The rectangle's transparency level and base color are known (40%, #FFFF00). Finally, the image's colors are limited to a palette, so no anti-alias or blurred-in pixels

Comment: I could write something to loop through each pixel to look for either magenta or "orange", and have the rgb/alpha values of said pixel adjusted to what I need, but I'm hoping there's a more simple way of achieving that

Comment: Obviously I'd still need to account for when an "orange" patch appears in other areas that are not part of a yellow rectangle

Comment: Is this a layered or flat image?

Comment: @BillyKerr flat

Comment: So in effect you don't have a rectangle and a circle at all, you have 3 different pieces and only 1 image. To be honest it would probably be quicker to recreate this from scratch using layers. What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?  At the moment your question reads a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: i used gimp's image to alpha. https://imgur.com/a/dzXV61X

Comment: That's a partial solution. It removes the magenta if you make it transparent and subtracts it fom the orange, so there's transparent  yellow generated. But the overlapping blue and yellow goes bust. It's still a partial solution, so show it as answer with example. I didn't invent it.

Comment: Does the example image you post here resemble the *actual* image you want to manipulate? Or is it very simplified? The paradox seems to be that for such a simple image it's quick to draw it again manually, but for a large and complex image it's impossible to automate because no program or script will be able to know whether an orange pixel is "truly" orange or comes from overlaying a transparent yellow.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have images generated from simulation software I haven't wrote. The software draws objects on top of a solid background and with a color palette of my choice. For my use case I want to remove the background and recreate the transparency on these images, just as illustrated in the last example. If I had layered images this wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @wolff example is a bit stripped down but is exactly what I need. I think I wasn't clear enough on the fact that I have a large number of images to process. No matter how simple the image or how limited the palette is, it's just impossible to go through them all one by one

Comment: If you have a alpha channel then yes this can be done automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recipe for an action in Photoshop, which works for this exact image (or other images using the same colors and principle). I suspect that the images you want to process have might have other or additional colors or some unknown complexity which could make this method worthless (or at least in need of tweaking).

You mention in comments that your images use a fixed palette and don't have any anti-alias or blurred-in pixels. But the example you post actually has anti-aliasing, so I start out by reducing the number of used colors to exactly 4 so the example image matches what you say you have:

[image]

---

- In the *Actions* panel, press *Create new action* and *Record* to start recording a new action.
- Double-click the *Background* layer to convert it to an ordinary layer. (If it already is, you can omit this.)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy selection to clipboard.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect.
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Channel Mixer* with the following settings to create a grayscale image where the magenta and orange pixels become white.
  [image]
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Threshold* with the following settings to make every non-white pixel black.
  [image]
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Gradient Map* setup to go from blue (RGB(0, 0, 255)) to white to turn all black pixels blue and leave the white pixels unchanged.
  [image]
- Double-click the layer to enter its *Blending Options*. Under *Blend If > This Layer*, pull the rightmost slider one tick to the left to make the white pixels transparent.
  [image]
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copy of the original we made before into a new layer.
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Channel Mixer* with the following settings to create a grayscale image where the magenta and blue pixels become white.
  [image]
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Threshold* with the following settings to make every non-white pixel black.
  [image]
- Use *Image > Adjustments > Gradient Map* setup to go from yellow (RGB(255, 255, 0)) to white to turn all black pixels yellow and leave the white pixels unchanged.
  [image]
- Double-click the top layer to enter its *Blending Options*. Under *Blend If > This Layer*, pull the rightmost slider one tick to the left to make the white pixels transparent.
  [image]
- In the *Layers* panel, set the *Opacity* of the top layer to *60%* (I just measured this).
  [image]
- Use *Layer > Merge Visible* to merge the two layers into one.

This should give you the wanted result *for an image with these specific values*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess no automate can decide how to construct the wanted original if there's no other facts than used colors - the same result can be got with numerous different layerings.

I guess redrawing with layers is not especially pleasant option if the actual image is complex and has a wide palette. But you can try to make selections with the magic wand. It should work well if there's no edge blurs. Turn anti-alias OFF. You can insert and subtract parts to or from the selection by holding Shift or Alt keys.

Try also Select > Color range with zero fuzziness.

Here the bottom layer is used to make the selections and color fills (blue and yellow) are inserted to different new layers :

[image]

Magic wand tool options allow selections in certain selected layer, only remember to switch to a new empty layer before inserting color.

I do not recommend using directly without selection Paint Bucket's possibility to fill certain color tolerance area. Making a selection gives a possibility to see the area to be colored.

Finally the transparency is inserted to the known transparent color layers and the original is closed:

[image]